# Remove "Object" key on a JSON object

Tags: php, ajax, json

I'm working on a suggest select (using [selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) with the example [customization.html](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/examples/customization.html) without theme changer) and i have a problem trying to connect my database to this select 
I need a format like this one in select.options to make my select working :

```
[{id:'1',title:'test',url:'testurl'}
 {id:'2',title:'test2',url:'testurl2'}
 ...
]
```

With the PHP request, I create a JSON object looking like this but when I'm receiving it in JS, "Object" keys appear from nowhere and ruined my JSON.
My PHP request (using PDO) is pretty simple :

```
    $result='[';
    $query = $bdd->prepare("SELECT id, login, name, surname FROM users WHERE id!=:id");
    $query->execute(array( ':id' => $_SESSION["id"]));
    while($row = $query->fetch())
    {
        $id = $row[0];
        $login = $row[1];
        $name = $row[2];
        $surname = $row[3];
        if($first != 1) 
            $result .= ','; 
        else
            $first =0;
        $result.='{"id":"'.$id.'",
                    "titre":"'.$login.'",
                    "url":"'.$name.' '.$surname.'"}'; 
    }
    $result.=']';
    return $result;
```

Finally, this is how I get it on my JS script :

```
ajaxCall("getPeople",null/*datas*/,false/*asynchronous*/,function(result){

                var newvalue = [];
                for(var root in result["result"])
                   newvalue.push(result["result"][root]);

                console.log(newvalue);

                return newvalue;
            });
```

And in the console logs I receive this JSON, where there are "Object" keys before each item, and which doesn't work with the select from selectize :

```
[Object { id="2",  titre="test",  url=" "}, Object { id="7",  titre="test2",  url=" "}, Object { id="8",  titre="test3",  url=" "}]
```

So do you have any ideas of removing these keys, or modifying my JSON object so that he can work with the selectize options format ?
Thank you !!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: It is more or less what I've done about this damn select :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not build JSON code yourself. Use `json_encode`:

```
$result = array();
$query = $bdd->prepare("SELECT id, login, name, surname FROM users WHERE id!=:id");
$query->execute(array( ':id' => $_SESSION["id"]));
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    $result[] = array(
        'id'    => $row[0],
        // Are you sure it's spelled "titre"? You wrote 'title' elsewhere.
        'titre' => $row[1],
        'url'   => "{$row[2]} {$row[3]}",
    );
);

// Output to browser
Header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8");
die(json_encode($result));
```

I think that you might be able to directly use the data above:

```
ajaxCall(
    "getPeople",
    null/*datas*/,
    false/*asynchronous*/,
    function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        // Debugging, the Viking way.
        prompt("I got this and no mistake", JSON.stringify(result));
        return result;
    });
```

## Use with selectize()

The example you posted should work like this. You cannot run selectize until you do have your data, so you do:

```
$.get('/path/to/getpeople.php', function(result) {
    // If we're here, the call succeeded
    $('#select-links').selectize({
        ...
        options: result, <-- here it goes!
        render: ...
    });
 });
```

The JSON will work; be sure to send the Content-Header for JSON, and to verify the fields are 'id', 'title', and 'url'.

Actually you can replace everywhere 'url' with 'fullname' if you want; apparently selectize only uses that field in the rendering function.

Comment: I never tried using json_encode : it returns exactly the same, but it's easier to understand and i don't fail at creating my own JSON object, thank you for bringing me this idea :)

However, I have the same problem with your method.
My PHP sent the JSON object in the good format but my JS added "Object" key before each item

Comment: You're sure it's not a red herring? Maybe that's how your console shows an array [ ] of dictionaries { } (they're sometimes called *objects*). Just to be sure, I added a test with stringify.

Comment: I'd rather give a closer look at that *titre* instead of *title*; is that the way it ought to be?

Comment: You taught me a new expresion ^^ ! Well it returns the same although it is in the good format in the prompt. THen, I really don't get why it doesn't show up on my selectize options. Does "options: getPeople();" work to fill the options array ?

Comment: Then I guess the problem is from the selectize library .. I'm learning how to use it but i don't see how I can connect it to my database. Thank you for your tips :)

Comment: I've posted you some code, let me know how it goes. You can also ask a new question based on what you expected and what actually did happen.

Comment: DAMN YOU'RE A GENIUS !! I didn't think about it, and it works well, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I tested out your PHP script and it seems to return valid JSON. For example:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "titre": "login",
        "url": "name username"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "titre": "login",
        "url": "name username"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "titre": "login",
        "url": "name username"
    }
]
```

In your JavaScript, try the following:

```
ajaxCall("getPeople",null/*datas*/,false/*asynchronous*/,function(result){
    console.log(result);
    return result;
});
```

JavaScript should automatically convert `result` into a "JSON" object.